# How to use a variable int within a filename string in C++/openFrameworks

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I am a total new guy to C++, as I am used to Processing, but for a project I have to make something in openFrameworks, a C++ framework. I am trying to load a movie each time a condition is triggered. I generate a random number, and then the videoplayer should load the movie that contains that number. Something like this:

```
 else if ( myByte > 130 ){
    float ranNumb = ofRandom(1, 5);
    int rounded = (int)ranNumb;
    cout << rounded << "\n";
    myPlayer.loadMovie("movies/testMovie_", rounded,".mp4");
}
```

Obviously the last line does not work in C++/OpenFrameworks. I am used to Processing and there I would just use the "+" operator to combine the string with the rounded variable. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use `std::string`'s concatenation functions and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openFrameworks provides the `ofToString()` function that will convert your `int` into a string. You can use it like this:

```
myPlayer.loadMovie("movies/testMovie_" + ofToString(rounded) + ".mp4");
```

Documentation: [ofToString](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/utils/ofUtils.html#!show_ofToString)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully C++11 is available, so you can do:

```
myPlayer.loadMovie(std::string("movies/testMovie_") + std::to_string(rounded) + ".mp4");
```

Comment: It isn't available with oF 0.8.4 but will be with version 0.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I find std::stringstream useful.

```
std::string pfn; // derived path file name
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "movies/testMovie_" << rounded;
    pfn = ss.str();
} 
cout << pfn << "\n";
myPlayer.loadMovie(pfn);
```